# use cakephp helper in controller

Tags: cakephp

I have a helper which change different strings to dates.
By this +5 becomes 2012-11-17 (5 days from today), 5 becomes 2012-11-05 (this year, this month, given day).

I would like to use the same thing in my controller.

```
App::uses('EasyDateHelper', 'View/Helper');
App::uses('View', 'View');
$this->View = new View($this->Controller);
$easyDate = new EasyDateHelper($this->View);
```

This code works well, but i would like to know if there is a better / simpler way to do.

Comment: you did not specify your cakephp version!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, there is.
Don't make it a helper!

Helpers are by design only for the view level.
If you need it in a controller, your design is wrong.

So make it a lib class etc and use it in your controllers this way.
and either use the same lib in your helpers or make a wrapper helper (similar to TextHelper for String, NumberHelper for CakeNumber, TimeHelper for CakeTime etc) to easily access the methods in your view scope.

For more complex solutions take a look at Sessions:

```
CakeSession is the lib class.
SessionComponent wraps it for the controller layer
SessionHelper wraps it for the view layer
```

For a Lib "DateLib" (you can name it whatever you like as long as the class name is unique throughout app and core):
Either put it in /Lib/ or /Lib/PackageName whereas PackageName can be defined by you (e.g. "Utility"). It is better to group by PackageName instead of putting it in Lib directly.

```
/Lib/Utility/DateLib.php
```

And in your code:

```
App::uses('DateLib', 'Utility');

$date = DateLib::format(); // for static methods

$DateLib = new DateLib();
$date = $DateLib->format(); // creating an extra object here
```

if you can work with static methods you should. this is also the way cake does it for the CakeTime, CakeNumber and String classes (see the code for details).

Comment: Where should I put my lib class?